# Can i put not null constraint to FK?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Well I tried to make my own company database by ERD. But when i make some relation, it has it's own ID and Foreign key. But this relation must need FK so i make it to not null. At first, I think FK need to be PK, but i remember PK need to be minimal. It already have ID so if i add FK to PK it goes to not minimal. What could i do?

Should i need to make Foreign key to PK or just put FK to not null. So now I think i need to make it to not null constraint. Relation what i want to make is evaluation and project. I want to ask about evaluation.

Comment: We can't really design your system for you, because we don't know full spec of it. What is the specific perceived problem you are trying to solve? Why not indeed simply make it a non-null FK?

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like the structure of order and orderdetail.
You'll have an order number as primary key of ORDER and a line number as primary key (per order) in orderdetail. Hence in a relational database the ORDERDETAIL table will have a primary key of ordernumber and linenumber. Obviously both columns must be defined not null.

The same is true in your PROJECT and EVALUATION. A project is evaluated in zero or more evaluations. The PROJECT will have a project-number as primary key. The evaluations are counted per project. The table will have a primary key of project-number and evaluation-number, both not null. (One can't evaluate a non existing project)